# How do I change the name of a disconnected network adaptor

Tags: powershell, networking

I have a set of computers in which I update the NetAdaptor name of a USB Ethernet adaptor to visually signify (in ipconfig/wirehark/etc) it is a special network.

Recently, one of the Ethernet adaptors failed. I replaced it with a new USB NIC, however when I attempted to set up my new adaptor with `Rename-NetAdaptor -Name "Ethernet 3" -NewName "AuxilaryNet"`
it returned `Rename-NetAdapter : {Object Exists} An attempt was made to create an object and the object name already existed.`

I need to reuse the old adaptors name. I cannot seem to find a way to rename or remove the missing adaptor, as it does not show up in `Get-NetAdapter -includeHidden`.  It DOES show up in `get-pnpdevice -class net`
however, I am stumped on what I can do with it.

I would like to be able to script the solution, I have found a manual way to remove the disconnected device in device manager which allows me to reuse the NIC name.

Comment: Can you not just remove the entry?

Comment: Did you try to remove the old adapater in your device manager?

Comment: I can manually go into device manager, show hidden devices, find the disconnected network device and delete it. However, I need a way to do those actions through a script.